# Does anyone know what's the plugin for this Comment Section?

Tags: plugins, comments, theme-twenty-eleven

http://twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com/readability-test/

The default Twenty Elevn Theme's [shwocase site has a nice comments section](http://twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com/readability-test/) (see link above) that allows user to connect to other services for authentications (like twitter) to comment. It's nice in a way that it doesn't seems to relay on other third party plugin like Disqus to manage my site's comment.

Anyone know what's this plugin is called ?

The default Twenty Eleven has a different comment section (layout and method to comment). I'm looking for the one from the showcase site, can't find any info regarding the comment section.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not a plugin, but a core feature for WordPress.com which is not the open source version of WordPress. While it does run on the same software, it has some features that are not available to download or to use on anywhere else but WordPress.com. You could however get the alternative, [OpenID](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/).

Comment: Thanks @Asko OpenID is okay, but worked not as sleek as the one from WordPress.com

Any other alternatives that may serve the same feature you know of ?

Comment: OpenID seemed the most solid one, however, according to Mashable's post back in June - http://mashable.com/2011/06/07/wordpress-comments-facebook-twitter/, the exact thing that WordPress.com uses might be coming soon to Automattic's Jetpack plugin - http://jetpack.me/ (the company behind WordPress). You might also consider Disqus - http://disqus.com/, which is also, if I'm not mistaking, available as a WordPress plugin.